# pseudocode, clever-ref. display (algorithm number, line of code)

Tags: cleveref, pseudocode

I have several algorithms and want to be able to have clever-ref automatically generate citations like

`\cref{alg1-line1}`: Algorithm 1, Line 1

`\cref{alg2-line44}`: Algorithm 2, Line 44

preferably with hyperlinks. How can I do it?

```
    \begin{algorithm}
      \caption{foo}\label{alg:foo}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
          \Procedure{foo}{}
          \State Some code \label{alg1-line1}
          \EndProcedure
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}

    \begin{algorithm}
      \caption{bar}\label{alg:bar}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
          \Procedure{bar}{}
          \State Some more code \label{alg2-line44}
          \EndProcedure
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
```